# Firewall hole punching

Tags: network, firewalls, tcp

I'm interested in doing my thesis on Firewall hole punching.

Hole Punching: A way to exploit NAT to open a connection TCP or UDP between a Client and a Server. What I'm looking for is a reason this would be a valid research area, and how it would help for me to do research on this.

Comment: Please explain 'hole punching'. Do you mean using services that the firewall explicitly blocks, or using allowed services in ways not intended, or ...? Don't say "all of those" ...

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of NAT, [ICE, STUN ecc..] any ideas are still welcome

Comment: so, you want to study employing covert channels to create hidden streams of communication through a firewall?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am reading on, ATM I'm reading on ICMP NAT punching

Comment: Please edit your question to explain 'hole punching' - I voted to reopen.

Comment: Ho do I re open this question ?

Comment: People vote to reopen

Answer (score 2):

Firewall hole punching is what we call **security through obscurity**, which is never a good idea because your whole security mechanism *may* relay on the hidden information, which is in this case the process of opening a port in the firewall.

Because this process is hidden you may think your system is 100% safe. Think about cases such:

- MITM - someone sniffing your data and taking notes of the hole punching process. Boom your security is gone with the wind.
- Brute forcing the process - what happen if I try to guess your punching process? Remeber there are only 65536 ports.

You see? there is always a need for a lower/higher level security mechanism to protect your system anyway. Someone may argue it is a waste of resources only.

You get the idea...